# How to format this txt as a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a txt file formatted like this:

```
002 lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

   asdfgjkl;
   info: bacon

003 lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

   jkl;hgfdsa
   info: bacon

004 lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

   notes about 004
   info: bacon
```

and so on (~ 2000), with spaces between the numbered line and the notes line

I would like to convert each numbered entry (which includes the three lines of text) into a dictionary (to be later added to a csv), so that each key would look like this

```
002:['lorem ipsum...','asdfgjkl;','bacon2']
```

I've been able to separate the text file into lines, but it's unclear to me how to join these lines into one and separate out the values. If I join  each numbered entry into one line, there aren't clear delineators for the 2nd line of the entry. If I keep them separately, it's unclear how to make sure they can eventually end up together.

Comment: Please add at least one more entry and explain what is your definition of a "paragraph." What have you tried so far? please post your code even if it did not fully work.

Comment: How does that input turn into that output? Shouldn't it be `2: ['lorem ipsum lorem ipsum', 'notes about 002', 'info: bacon']`?

Comment: I'd like to remove the `'info'` part of `'info: bacon'`, as it's going to be the header of the column in the csv.

Comment: Yes, please include your coded attempt as well as a more thorough definition of how the data should be converted. For instance how does `002` in your text file become a key of `001` in your dictionary? Furthermore is the key supposed to be an integer `1` or string `"001"` (with leading zeros? This question is missing key information for answerers to be able to help.

Comment: The key should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Go through line by line and see if the first "word" is numeric. Assuming Notes will not start with a number by itself, every new "paragraph" will be initialized into the dict in the first `if` statement below.

```
result = {} # initialize dictionary
currentLineNumber = '' # keep track of current line "number" (note, it's a string not an int)

for line in file:
    if line and line.split()[0].isnumeric():
        # Found a line with numbers, it's a new item to be added to dict
        currentLineNumber = line.split()[0]
        result[currentLineNumber] = [' '.join(line.split()[1:])] # note, the key to this dict is of type str
    elif line:
        # Found a line with text, append to list for current line number
        line = line.strip() # Remove leading/trailing spaces
        if line.startswith('info: '):
            line = line[6:] # Removing 'info:' by slicing, assuming every "paragraph" has this info section you're trying to remove
        result[currentLineNumber].append(line)
```